# Theming order by taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a view that gets all the nodes from a certain type and shows them on a page; every node is categorized by a taxonomy term. 
I created a custom .template file to theme the view using the row style, but what I really would like to do is order all the nodes under a category, for example:

- category 1

  - node 1
  - node 7
  - node 15
- category 2

  - node 2
  - node 6

How do I do this?

Comment: Are the categories the taxonomy terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note steps describe below are for D6:
Create u r view using drupal views module
Select the appropriate fields, 
under filter field, Select the taxonomy , and select appropriate taxonomy term 
Select the appropriate fields (which you will like to display).
change the output style to table or whatever you prefer 
and there you have it

Hope it helps.